# Can the #pragma unroll statement be used to clean up compiler pre-evaluated code?

Tags: c++, optimization, cuda, dry, compiler-optimization

In NVIDIA's well made [reduction optimization documentation](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/assets/cuda/files/reduction.pdf), they end up with a warpReduce that looks like:

```
Template <unsigned int blockSize>
__device__ void warpReduce(volatile int* sdata, int tid) {
    if (blockSize >= 64) sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 32]; 
    if (blockSize >= 32) sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 16]; 
    if (blockSize >= 16) sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 8]; 
    if (blockSize >= 8) sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 4]; 
    if (blockSize >= 4) sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 2]; 
    if (blockSize >= 2) sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 1]; 
}
```

This hurts my sensibility as a proponent of [Don't Repeat Yourself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself), why didn't they save programmer time and introduce constructs more like

```
Template <unsigned int blockSize>
__device__ void warpReduce(volatile int* sdata, int tid) {
    #pragma unroll(6)
    for (int i = 64; i>1; i>>=1){
        if (blockSize >= i) sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + (i/2)]; 
    }
}
```

Will this compile to the same code? Or does this confuse the compiler too much to optimize it away? I know the case statement suffers from a similar DRY issue, but I don't know that there's a way to get around that, since it maps runtime inputs to compiler time constant defined template kernels, but I don't see how making programmers need to write out the same thing a fair number of times is helpful.

Not to mention, if the warp size ever changes, which it may not (but who knows) the code I introduced will be much easier to change, and could even use a constant to define the warp size, allowing for one change to change the optimization here, and anywhere else that relies on the warp size.

Very related subquestion, I read using the built-in `warpSize` is questionable for a compiler optimization reason as well. Otherwise I would have included it in the code above. Going to the definition in `device_launch_parameters.h`, it calls a built-in device query `__cudaGet_warpSize()`. If this isn't an issue, NVIDIA could have provided in that document a complete, generalized optimization of `warpReduce` for reference, but didn't, and I would like to know why?

**Tl;dr:** Can I write this as

```
Template <unsigned int blockSize>
__device__ void warpReduce(volatile int* sdata, int tid) {
    #pragma unroll(6)
    for (int i = warpSize * 2; i>1; i>>=1){
        if (blockSize >= i) sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + (i/2)]; 
    }
}
```

and enjoy the same optimization as in their documentation?

Comment: Why not try it?  All the [binary utilities](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-binary-utilities/index.html#abstract) you need are available so you can compare the machine code yourself for each case.  Also, pragma begins with a #, not an @

Comment: Shoot. I've been doing too much with Python decorators. Thanks for the correction. I planned on it, but I wanted to see if I was wasting my time, and I was curious why this wasn't brought up on SO before. It seems like something useful to know. If I get an answer before someone else I'll put it up here. But I have other work to do first.

Comment: I *think* they might have written it that way just to emphasize the semantics.

Comment: I'm hoping that's true. It's still leading people (especially in my workplace, which is why I asked) to do extra work for no bonus performance (theoretically).

Comment: One of the advantages of the documented approach vs. your for-loop is that I can look at the documented approach with only a basic knowledge of compiler optimization behavior, and predict that the optimizer will drop out lines of code which are not needed for the given template parameter.  I can predict optimal behavior.  In your case, we have to ask lengthy questions like this one.  `#pragma unroll` doesn't *eliminate* the for loop, it just expands the body. *And* in order to force correctness, the compiler will actually add *additional* code to protect against un-optimal loop counts.

Comment: @RobertCrovella I can agree with you, except on one point: Looking at the documented code, I have no idea why it starts at 64 unless I read the document or know CUDA enough to know the whole warp size deal and why it matters. At least with my code, I know that 32 is the warp size, and can figure it out based on that (and Google). Mind you, CUDA is currently mostly for experienced developers, but it never hurts to assume inexperienced developers may eventually look at the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an insightful observation (I think).  Based on my test code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

template <unsigned int blockSize>
__device__ void warpReduce1(volatile int* sdata, int tid) {
    if (blockSize >= 64) sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 32];
    if (blockSize >= 32) sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 16];
    if (blockSize >= 16) sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 8];
    if (blockSize >= 8) sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 4];
    if (blockSize >= 4) sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 2];
    if (blockSize >= 2) sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 1];
}

template <unsigned int blockSize>
__device__ void warpReduce2(volatile int* sdata, int tid) {
    #pragma unroll 6
    for (int i = 64; i>1; i>>=1){
        if (blockSize >= i) sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + (i/2)];
    }
}

template <unsigned int blockSize>
__global__ void reduce6(int *g_idata, int *g_odata, unsigned int n) {
  extern __shared__ int sdata[];
  unsigned int tid = threadIdx.x;
  unsigned int i = blockIdx.x*(blockSize*2) + tid;
  unsigned int gridSize = blockSize*2*gridDim.x;
  sdata[tid] = 0;
  while (i < n){sdata[tid] += g_idata[i] + g_idata[i+blockSize]; i += gridSize; }
  __syncthreads();
  if (blockSize >= 512) { if (tid < 256) { sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 256]; } __syncthreads(); }
  if (blockSize >= 256) { if (tid < 128) { sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 128]; } __syncthreads(); }
  if (blockSize >= 128) { if (tid < 64) { sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 64]; } __syncthreads(); }
  if (tid < 32) warpReduce1<blockSize>(sdata, tid);
  if (tid == 0) g_odata[blockIdx.x] = sdata[0];
}

#define DSIZE 1048576
#define BSIZE 256
#define NBLKS 64

int main(){
  int *h_data, *d_idata, *d_odata;
  h_data=(int *)malloc(DSIZE * sizeof(int));
  cudaMalloc(&d_idata, DSIZE * sizeof(int));
  cudaMalloc(&d_odata, NBLKS * sizeof(int));
  for (int i = 0; i < DSIZE; i++) h_data[i] = rand()%2;
  cudaMemcpy(d_idata, h_data, DSIZE*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  reduce6<BSIZE><<<64, BSIZE>>>(d_idata, d_odata, DSIZE);
  cudaMemcpy(h_data, d_odata, NBLKS*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  return 0;
}
```

It appears that the generated machine code is identical:

```
Fatbin elf code:
================
arch = sm_20
code version = [1,7]
producer = <unknown>
host = linux
compile_size = 64bit
identifier = t576.cu

        code for sm_20

Fatbin elf code:
================
arch = sm_20
code version = [1,7]
producer = cuda
host = linux
compile_size = 64bit
identifier = t576.cu

        code for sm_20
                Function : _Z7reduce6ILj256EEvPiS0_j
        .headerflags    @"EF_CUDA_SM20 EF_CUDA_PTX_SM(EF_CUDA_SM20)"
        /*0000*/         MOV R1, c[0x1][0x100];                            /* 0x2800440400005de4 */
        /*0008*/         S2R R0, SR_CTAID.X;                               /* 0x2c00000094001c04 */
        /*0010*/         S2R R2, SR_TID.X;                                 /* 0x2c00000084009c04 */
        /*0018*/         MOV R4, c[0x0][0x14];                             /* 0x2800400050011de4 */
        /*0020*/         MOV R10, RZ;                                      /* 0x28000000fc029de4 */
        /*0028*/         ISCADD R8, R0, R2, 0x9;                           /* 0x4000000008021d23 */
        /*0030*/         SHL.W R3, R2, 0x2;                                /* 0x6000c0000820de03 */
        /*0038*/         SHL R9, R4, 0x9;                                  /* 0x6000c00024425c03 */
        /*0040*/         ISETP.GE.U32.AND P0, PT, R8, c[0x0][0x30], PT;    /* 0x1b0e4000c081dc03 */
        /*0048*/         STS [R3], RZ;                                     /* 0xc9000000003fdc85 */
        /*0050*/         SSY 0xf0;                                         /* 0x6000000260000007 */
        /*0058*/     @P0 NOP.S;                                            /* 0x40000000000001f4 */
        /*0060*/         MOV32I R11, 0x4;                                  /* 0x180000001002dde2 */
        /*0068*/         IMAD.U32.U32 RZ, R1, RZ, RZ;                      /* 0x207e0000fc1fdc03 */
        /*0070*/         SSY 0xe8;                                         /* 0x60000001c0000007 */
        /*0078*/         NOP;                                              /* 0x4000000000001de4 */
        /*0080*/         IMAD.U32.U32 R6.CC, R8, R11, c[0x0][0x20];        /* 0x2017800080819c03 */
        /*0088*/         IADD R5, R8, 0x100;                               /* 0x4800c00400815c03 */
        /*0090*/         IMAD.U32.U32.HI.X R7, R8, R11, c[0x0][0x24];      /* 0x209680009081dc43 */
        /*0098*/         IMAD.U32.U32 R4.CC, R5, R11, c[0x0][0x20];        /* 0x2017800080511c03 */
        /*00a0*/         IADD R8, R8, R9;                                  /* 0x4800000024821c03 */
        /*00a8*/         LD.E R7, [R6];                                    /* 0x840000000061dc85 */
        /*00b0*/         IMAD.U32.U32.HI.X R5, R5, R11, c[0x0][0x24];      /* 0x2096800090515c43 */
        /*00b8*/         ISETP.LT.U32.AND P0, PT, R8, c[0x0][0x30], PT;    /* 0x188e4000c081dc03 */
        /*00c0*/         LD.E R4, [R4];                                    /* 0x8400000000411c85 */
        /*00c8*/         IADD R5, R7, R10;                                 /* 0x4800000028715c03 */
        /*00d0*/         IADD R10, R5, R4;                                 /* 0x4800000010529c03 */
        /*00d8*/     @P0 BRA 0x80;                                         /* 0x4003fffe800001e7 */
        /*00e0*/         NOP.S;                                            /* 0x4000000000001df4 */
        /*00e8*/         STS.S [R3], R10;                                  /* 0xc900000000329c95 */
        /*00f0*/         IMAD.U32.U32 RZ, R1, RZ, RZ;                      /* 0x207e0000fc1fdc03 */
        /*00f8*/         BAR.RED.POPC RZ, RZ, RZ, PT;                      /* 0x50ee0000ffffdc04 */
        /*0100*/         ISETP.GT.U32.AND P0, PT, R2, 0x7f, PT;            /* 0x1a0ec001fc21dc03 */
        /*0108*/    @!P0 LDS R5, [R3];                                     /* 0xc100000000316085 */
        /*0110*/    @!P0 LDS R4, [R3+0x200];                               /* 0xc100000800312085 */
        /*0118*/    @!P0 IADD R4, R5, R4;                                  /* 0x4800000010512003 */
        /*0120*/    @!P0 STS [R3], R4;                                     /* 0xc900000000312085 */
        /*0128*/         BAR.RED.POPC RZ, RZ, RZ, PT;                      /* 0x50ee0000ffffdc04 */
        /*0130*/         ISETP.GT.U32.AND P0, PT, R2, 0x3f, PT;            /* 0x1a0ec000fc21dc03 */
        /*0138*/    @!P0 LDS R5, [R3];                                     /* 0xc100000000316085 */
        /*0140*/    @!P0 LDS R4, [R3+0x100];                               /* 0xc100000400312085 */
        /*0148*/    @!P0 IADD R4, R5, R4;                                  /* 0x4800000010512003 */
        /*0150*/    @!P0 STS [R3], R4;                                     /* 0xc900000000312085 */
        /*0158*/         SSY 0x240;                                        /* 0x6000000380000007 */
        /*0160*/         BAR.RED.POPC RZ, RZ, RZ, PT;                      /* 0x50ee0000ffffdc04 */
        /*0168*/         ISETP.GT.U32.AND P0, PT, R2, 0x1f, PT;            /* 0x1a0ec0007c21dc03 */
        /*0170*/     @P0 NOP.S;                                            /* 0x40000000000001f4 */
        /*0178*/         SHL.W R3, R2, 0x2;                                /* 0x6000c0000820de03 */
        /*0180*/         LDS R5, [R3];                                     /* 0xc100000000315c85 */
        /*0188*/         LDS R4, [R3+0x80];                                /* 0xc100000200311c85 */
        /*0190*/         IADD R6, R5, R4;                                  /* 0x4800000010519c03 */
        /*0198*/         STS [R3], R6;                                     /* 0xc900000000319c85 */
        /*01a0*/         LDS R5, [R3];                                     /* 0xc100000000315c85 */
        /*01a8*/         LDS R4, [R3+0x40];                                /* 0xc100000100311c85 */
        /*01b0*/         IADD R7, R5, R4;                                  /* 0x480000001051dc03 */
        /*01b8*/         STS [R3], R7;                                     /* 0xc90000000031dc85 */
        /*01c0*/         LDS R5, [R3];                                     /* 0xc100000000315c85 */
        /*01c8*/         LDS R4, [R3+0x20];                                /* 0xc100000080311c85 */
        /*01d0*/         IADD R6, R5, R4;                                  /* 0x4800000010519c03 */
        /*01d8*/         STS [R3], R6;                                     /* 0xc900000000319c85 */
        /*01e0*/         LDS R5, [R3];                                     /* 0xc100000000315c85 */
        /*01e8*/         LDS R4, [R3+0x10];                                /* 0xc100000040311c85 */
        /*01f0*/         IADD R7, R5, R4;                                  /* 0x480000001051dc03 */
        /*01f8*/         STS [R3], R7;                                     /* 0xc90000000031dc85 */
        /*0200*/         LDS R5, [R3];                                     /* 0xc100000000315c85 */
        /*0208*/         LDS R4, [R3+0x8];                                 /* 0xc100000020311c85 */
        /*0210*/         IADD R6, R5, R4;                                  /* 0x4800000010519c03 */
        /*0218*/         STS [R3], R6;                                     /* 0xc900000000319c85 */
        /*0220*/         LDS R5, [R3];                                     /* 0xc100000000315c85 */
        /*0228*/         LDS R4, [R3+0x4];                                 /* 0xc100000010311c85 */
        /*0230*/         IADD R4, R5, R4;                                  /* 0x4800000010511c03 */
        /*0238*/         STS.S [R3], R4;                                   /* 0xc900000000311c95 */
        /*0240*/         ISETP.NE.AND P0, PT, R2, RZ, PT;                  /* 0x1a8e0000fc21dc23 */
        /*0248*/     @P0 BRA.U 0x278;                                      /* 0x40000000a00081e7 */
        /*0250*/    @!P0 MOV32I R3, 0x4;                                   /* 0x180000001000e1e2 */
        /*0258*/    @!P0 LDS R2, [RZ];                                     /* 0xc100000003f0a085 */
        /*0260*/    @!P0 IMAD.U32.U32 R4.CC, R0, R3, c[0x0][0x28];         /* 0x20078000a0012003 */
        /*0268*/    @!P0 IMAD.U32.U32.HI.X R5, R0, R3, c[0x0][0x2c];       /* 0x20868000b0016043 */
        /*0270*/    @!P0 ST.E [R4], R2;                                    /* 0x940000000040a085 */
        /*0278*/         EXIT;                                             /* 0x8000000000001de7 */
                ..........................................



Fatbin ptx code:
================
arch = sm_20
code version = [4,1]
producer = cuda
host = linux
compile_size = 64bit
compressed
identifier = t576.cu
```

whether I use:

```
  if (tid < 32) warpReduce1<blockSize>(sdata, tid);
```

or:

```
  if (tid < 32) warpReduce2<blockSize>(sdata, tid);
```

In retrospect, the compiler can easily determine the trip count of the for-loop:

```
    for (int i = 64; i>1; i>>=1){
```

And the unrolled loop will generate exactly the same sequence as the inline code.  Therefore the compiler generates the same code.